# Webkit Inspector not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: intel-xdk

I have looked all over the internet for a single thread on this topic and found none.

In version 277 (maybe prior since this is the first version I try Intel XDK), the webkit inspector does not stop on breakpoints, ever! In fact, the UI seems to have quite a lot of difficulty to deal with just setting up a break points. Several odd behaviours are noticed:

In the inspector, in the 'sources' tab, open a js file, than click on the left margin (on line numbers) and you will notice :

1) that it will not show the breakpoint. 
2) therefore you start clicking several times, and you notice that a break point is found in the breakpoint list (found on the right column of the inspector) for every click I made.

Important notes:

I'm very used to using the webkit inspector in Chrome, so I know that stopping on breakpoints works in other contexts or environments.

In this sense, I've tried to go ahead and prove this to myself, so I've tried this functionality in Node Webkit (since the XDK IDE is based on it), and I was surprise to observe that indeed this worked there as well.

This is why I believe it must be because I'm running the XDK on Windows 8.1. So I installed the SDK on my Mac at home. Same issue. So I tried Windows 7: same issue again.

The questions are, why the debugger doesn't work in the XDK? Has it worked in the past? How come no-one in the world seems to complain about this bug?

Comment: Please check the [Intel XDK forum](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=5186), a reply has been posted there.